# JavaOracle Exhausted Result

Tags: java

i have been try to fixed any error but still get exhausted resultset error.  is there anything wrong in my code?

```
   stmt=con.createStatement();
   String sql = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER";
   rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);

   rs.next();
           int id_col = rs.getInt("CUSTOMER_ID");
           String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
           String name= rs.getString("CUSTOMER_NAME");
           String address = rs.getString("CUSTOMER_ADDRESS");
           String phone = rs.getString ("CUSTOMER_PHONE");
           String email = rs.getString ("CUSTOMER_EMAIL");

           textID.setText(id);
           textName.setText(name);
           textAddress.setText(address);
           textPhone.setText(phone);
           textEmail.setText(email);


    }
    catch (SQLException err) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ComputerShop.this,err.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like there's no data in your CUSTOMER table. Use `if (rs.next) { ... }` before set the data to check it.

Comment: @amilaisura the error is: *still get exhausted resultset error*.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from reading the code that it looks like SQL in java. If you are trying to select multiply rows from a single table for example, you could also do it this way.

```
public static void customerName(Connection b, String c) throws SQLException
{
    c = "'"+c+"'";

    try
    {
        b = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, password);
        b.clearWarnings();
        stmt = b.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT CONTACTNAME FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTOMERID =" + c); // this is basicly where you install the SQL code minus the ";" at the end.

        while(rs.next())
        {
            System.out.print(rs.getString("CONTACTNAME") + " ");
        }
    }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    finally
    {
        if(!b.isClosed())
        {
        b.close();  
        }

    }

}
```

I find this usually helps me keep everything clean and also organizes my code. This would be a method I would call from my main method where I connected to the database.